# How can I get Ivy to bundle dependencies for MY dependencies into their own jar?

Tags: jar, ivy

In my project, I have exactly one dependency (right now, it's early!) - Hibernate. In my Ivy config, I have the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="5.4.0.Final" conf="sources->sources"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="5.4.0.Final" conf="binaries->default"/>
</dependencies>
```

And in my build.xml, I have this:

```
<ivy:retrieve conf="sources" pattern="war/WEB-INF/lib/[conf]/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
<ivy:retrieve conf="binaries" pattern="war/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
```

Now, in my lib folder, I have a folder called sources with exactly one jar, `hibernate-core-sources.jar` - perfect!! But in the lib folder itself, I don't have exactly one jar - I have 18 jars, one for each of Hibernate's dependencies (and grandparent dependencies, etc.)

What I'd really like to see is something like `hibernate-core.jar` and `hibernate-core-deps.jar`.

Is something like this possible? If it isn't, would it be possible to have it be `hibernate-core.jar` and `my-app-deps.jar`? And if THAT isn't possible, can it just bundle it all into a single `my-app-deps.jar`?

I'm not very experienced with Ivy, so the more explicit your answer, the better!

Comment: Why do you need this? I mean you need dependencies of your dependency for you app to run.. Asking only because we may have an XY problem here :)

Comment: Because I like looking at my lib folder and seeing the things that I actually need to be able to use, not that happen to be a buried dependency of one of my dependencies. But, you're right, I could see how this could be a symptom of a bigger problem, but the reality is it's merely for aesthetic purposes. Ivy manages them all properly no matter what, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you have to be aware that when you build the classpath you may end um missing some classes and having `NoClassDefFoundError` thrown at runtime.
The solution is to call ivy [resolve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/use/resolve.html) once with `transitive` set to `false`, and second time with it being set to `true` (which is default). After each of these you have to call [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/use/retrieve.html) but with different retrieve patterns, so the non-transitive (`hibernate-core.jar`) to `lib` folder and transitive to a temp folder from which you could create `hibernate-core-deps.jar`.